# Linux distribution information of the HDInsight cluster

Tags: linux, azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I am going to do product certification on Linux HDInsight Hadoop cluster. This product is only certificated on RHEL and SUSE. As my account is not available now. Can some one tell me the specific distribution information of the Linux HDInsight Hadoop cluster? For example RHEL x.x or something else. Is is possible to custom the Linux distribution type when I create a cluster? I need these information to give an acurrate estimation of the certification scope.

Thank you very much,
Mason

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can some one tell me the specific distribution information of the
>   Linux HDInsight Hadoop cluster?

On Azure, Linux-based HDInsight is based on the Ubuntu Linux distribution. Different versions of HDInsight rely on different versions of Ubuntu.

The following screenshot lists the versions of HDInsight currently available, the corresponding Hortonworks Data Platform versions that they use, and their release dates.

[image]

More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-component-versioning#supported-hdinsight-versions).

> Is is possible to custom the Linux distribution type when I create a
>   cluster?

Based on my knowledge, for now, Azure does not support this.